# In Coded UI test cannot select weekdays

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I need to select a past weekday ( any previous weekday) from the applications calendar:
but the Coded UI Test method is not picking weekday properly. Can anyone please see what's wrong:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{
    public CodedUITest1()
    {
    }

    private DayOfWeek[] AllowedDays
    = { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
        DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday, };

    public void CodedUITestMethod1() {
       // this.UIMap.SelectApptdate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3));
        this.UIMap.SelectApptdate(
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Day.Equals(DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)
            : DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Day.Equals(DayOfWeek.Sunday)
              ? DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)
              : DateTime.Now.AddDays(-4)
        );
    }
 }
```

I have also overload that method in the `UIMap.cs` file as below:

```
public partial class UIMap
{
    public void SelectApptDate(DateTime date)
    {
        SelectApptDateParams.UIUicReqApptDateDateTimePickerDateTimeAsString
            = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

        SelectApptDate();
     }
 }
```

Comment: What is the "applications calendar"? There are many types of calendar entry screen and they have various facilities. Saying the "test method is not picking weekday properly" tells us nothing about what it is actually doing or not doing. You need to provide much more detail of the problem and what you have already tried.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to pick a date only weekdays from the calendar. when I  use: this.UIMap.SelectApptdate(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)); the test method picks a date that is 3 days in past. But I want to select a weekday in past or in future without selecting weekends.                                        Properties:                                                     Class Name: WindowsForms10.SysDateTimePick32.app.0.360e033
Control Type: DateTimePicker